# How to halt io.Copy(file, conn) in tcp client?

Tags: go, tcp

I'm new to go lang and I'm having trouble writing tcp code in go.

these are my code

```
// client
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "io"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    GetFileFromServer(conn, "test.txt")
}

func GetFileFromServer(conn net.Conn, fileName string) {
    file, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    conn.Write([]byte("get:" + fileName))
 
    _, err = io.Copy(file, conn) // **IT DOES NOT STOP!!**
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("GET DONE")
}
```

```
// server
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "net"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "os"
)

const BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
const DIR_PATH = "./serverFile"

func main() {
    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        go ConnHandle(conn)        
    }
}

func ConnHandle(conn net.Conn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
    _, err := conn.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    trimedBuffer := bytes.Trim(buffer, "\x00")
    command := strings.Split(string(trimedBuffer), ":")

    if command[0] == "get" {
        PutFileToClient(conn, command[1])
        return
    }
}

func PutFileToClient(conn net.Conn, fileName string) {

    file, err := os.Open(DIR_PATH + "\\" + fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(conn, file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    
    fmt.Println("PUT DONE")
}
```

----What I want----

1. server and client are excuted,
2. client sends to server "get:test.txt"
3. server receives it
4. server sends file to client
5. client receives it, and saves on file
6. terminate client

I think the reason "client's io.Copy" doesn't stop is because it keeps trying to read data from connection.

How fix or halt it?

Comment: Close the connection when the file is sent. Do not use defer to close the connection, that will only work when the function returns. Close the connection in the goroutine that handles the file copy. You can defer close it there.

Comment: Also you need to address letting the *client* know if there was a server-side error. A file open failure; or a short-read will go unnoticed on the client-side.

Comment: added a suggestion on how to add a file-size header to cover some of the potential server-side errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BurakSerdar mentioned the client never gets a `io.EOF` because the server never closes the connection stream.

```
func PutFileToClient(conn net.Conn, fileName string) {
    defer conn.Close() // ensures client gets a `io.EOF` on success *OR* failure

    // ...
}
```

However, there are some edge cases you need to be mindful of.

While error handling can be tracked on the server-side, from a client perspective it will be oblivious to these errors and save a file of:

- zero bytes (if server fails to open file); or
- partial bytes (if there server's `io.Copy` fails in the middle)

To address these cases, it would be advisable to write a file-size header at the beginning of your connection payload e.g.

### Server

- File Open:

  - Fails: `defer` closes conn (client will get zero bytes)
- Stat file-size

  - write file size as an 8-byte header (64-bit filesize covers any size) e.g.

    - `b := make([]byte, 8)`
    - `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(b, fsize)`
    - `n, err := io.Copy(conn, b)`
  - io.Copy file body as before

    - return on any error

### Client

- Read header into 8-byte buffer
- short-read (i.e. less than 8 bytes) no/bad header - server failed to get file
- unmarshal file-size header:

  - `fsize := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(b)`
- track bytes copied:

  - `n, err := io.Copy(file, conn)`
- verify `n == fsize` to ensure full payload was received.